# How to save group of shapes as JPG image?

Tags: excel, vba, image

I place a number of shapes on an image using VBA and want to save the whole group as a JPG.

```
Sub SaveImageTEST()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).SaveAsPicture "worldmap.jpg"
End Sub
```

The idea is to visualize data on a map:
[image]

Comment: [`SaveAsPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/publisher.shaperange.saveaspicture) looks like it is the Publisher Object Model, btw.

Comment: How would you do this manually?

Comment: Screenshot would be easy, but I need this running on a server to update a web-page...

Answer (score 1):

The best that I could come up with is to export as pdf, hopes this helps.

```
Sub SaveImage()
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))

    Set ch = ws.ChartObjects.Add(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height)
    shp.Select
    Selection.Copy

    ch.Chart.Paste
    Set tt = ch.Chart

    'tt.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="c:\outputFileName"
    tt.Export Filename:="C:\test.png", filtername:="PNG"

    ch.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution does not work for me as I need the graph on a webpage.

Comment: Ulrich I changed one line of code, now it should work.